# How To Prevent ERR_TIMEOUT From Epson TM-m30 Thermal Line Printer Timeout error in Printing Progress using SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4.2, thermal-printer, epson

I also tried with latest SDK for iOS of Epson thermal Line printer for model TM-M30  still having same error screenshot attached here .[image: While printing is in progress after few seconds got this error every time I press print button from my custom iOS Application.]

SDK link using in my iOS App as under;-
https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&pcat=3&scat=58

So, I need proper help from anyone whoever use Epson Thermal line printer Intregation with SDK for iOS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question article. What hardware/software configuration did you try? For example, the SDK contains user's manuals and sample programs. Do you use them to set up and test as described? Please add the details of such a situation.

Comment: @kunif - I can connect with the printer easily. But I am facing one issue that it prints ticket/receipt with some delay (after 5-6 secs).
I am using this iOS SDK with link is on question .
Steps:
1) Initialize printer 
2) preparing print-data
3) Connecting to printer
4) Begin transaction
5) Send data  
After printing data successfully  1) Ending transaction
 2) Disconnecting to printer 
 3) Clear buffer
 4) set printer to nil
This whole process is taking 5-6 seconds to complete.  So what is the best way to print data with minimal time.   Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The content that can be expressed in the comments is poor, so please add it to the article. Also, if the source code of those processes is presented, it will be easier to get an answer.